# 'Class SdFat' error message with Adafruit wave shield

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, adafruit

I'm using Arduino Uno and Adafruit Wave Shield, with the WaveRP library.
I was able to run the example programs of the waveRP library, but I try to connect a mic to the shield, didn't go well, so I returned to one of the examples to verify if the shield was working well and now is showing me this error message. I damaged the shield?

```
> Arduino:1.8.2 (Mac OS X), Tarjeta:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"
> 
> Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_waverp/examples/dapRP/dapRP.pde:
> In function 'void setup()': dapRP:31: error: 'class SdFat' has no
> member named 'init'    if (!sd.init(SPI_FULL_SPEED))
> sd.initErrorHalt();
> 
>            ^ Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_waverp/examples/dapRP/dapRP.pde:
> In function 'void play(SdBaseFile*)': dapRP:67: error: no matching
> function for call to 'SdBaseFile::readDir(dir_t&)'    while
> (dir->readDir(dirBuf) > 0) {    // Read every file in the directory
> one at a time
> 
>                              ^ Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_waverp/examples/dapRP/dapRP.pde:67:29:
> note: candidate is: In file included from 
> Documents/Arduino/libraries/SdFat/SdFile.h:24:0,
>                  from  Documents/Arduino/libraries/SdFat/SdFat.h:38,
>                  from Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_waverp/WaveRP.h:22,
>                  from Documents/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_waverp/examples/dapRP/dapRP.pde:4:
> Documents/Arduino/libraries/SdFat/SdBaseFile.h:325:10: note: int8_t
> SdBaseFile::readDir(dir_t*)    int8_t readDir(dir_t* dir);
> 
>           ^ Documents/Arduino/libraries/SdFat/SdBaseFile.h:325:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'dir_t {aka
> directoryEntry}' to 'dir_t* {aka directoryEntry*}' exit status 1
> 'class SdFat' has no member named 'init'
>
```

Comment: No, you didn't break the shield. That is a software error - a problem in your sketch. If it's an unmodified example maybe you need to reinstall the library.

Comment: @Majenko I reinstalled both libraries the SdFat one and the WaveRP, but it keeps saying the same